# why my response AJAX always return false, using database checker

Tags: php, ajax, database, continuous-integration

I want to check username in the form valaible or not avalaible to create. Then i use ajax for check in database without refrash page. Then i create this, but the response always return false. I try only controller with print_r, the function cek_user() can get value true and false. Please help how to my ajax return false or true.
Thank before.

I using ajax and CI

here my contoller User.php

```
public function cek_user()
{
  $username     = $this->input->post('user_name');
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_user where username='".$username."'");

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

and this my form add_user.php

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
          <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
</div>
<div id="chk_username" class="form-group col-md-6">

</div>
```

and this my ajax script add_user.php

```
$('#username').change(function(){

    var username = $('#username').val();

    if(username != "")
    {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "<?php echo base_url();?>user/cek_user",
            data    : { user_name:username },
            dataType: "text",
            success : function(response)
            {
                if (response == true) 
                {
                    $('#chk_username').html("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success'>Username tersedia</div>");
                    console.log("true");
                }
                else if(response == false)
                {
                    $('#chk_username').html("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-danger'>Username tidak tersedia</div>");
                    console.log("false");
                }  
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

how to get true or false value from this ajax script ?

Comment: How are you returning the result of `cek_user()` to the client? If you use `echo` then `true` will be echoed as `1` and `false` will be an empty string. If you're using JSON, you need to use `dataType: "json"` in the client.

Comment: What does CI have to do with this? This is an engineering process, it has nothing to do with how the code actually works.

Comment: @Barmar I mean that what is inputted in the username can be checked in the database using ajax, so where's the wrong one?

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` show?

Comment: If you're returning text, you should compare with a string: `if(response == "true")`

Comment: not show anything, should i replace it with echo, not **return** on the controller?

Comment: Probably. It depends on how you're calling the function. Are you using a framework?

Comment: yes, I using CI, i think return true not work, echo "true"; and using response == "true" best anser now. Thanks

Comment: CI is not a framework. **Continuous integration (CI) is the building and automated testing of the full software product on a frequent schedule: at least once a day, often several times a day and sometimes as often as after every check in to the version control system.**

Comment: @barmar, thank for explanation, now i'm just using localhost, next i will use it